# Strict Positive Definite Matrix in cvxpy python

Tags: cvxpy

I am trying to apply cvxpy python to solve an LMI

How can I define a strictly positive definite matrix here?

For about a matrix of order 10 for example this is the syntax

X = cp.Variable((100, 100), PSD=True)

but it is for X when X>=0

I need X>0.

I have read the cvxpy and search in it but there was not such an item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Strict inequalities are not possible because what does that mean when computations are done in finite precision floating numbers.

But you can do

(X - I*eps) is PSD

where I is the identity matrix and eps is small positive number say 1.0e-6.
It should not be too small.